# HttpListener only capturing some of traffic but not status code 302 redirects

Tags: c#, proxy, http-status-code-302, httplistener

I've inherited a proxy server using html listener but I've run into a problem.  The basic idea is that a web user connects to the proxy when trying to communicate with the webserver.  The proxy intercepts the request and sends it to the webserver.  The response is obtained, BUT it now seems I'm only capturing one of the possible streams coming back.  I'm able to capture the pages with status code 200 but not the status codes of 302.

Is this because I'm only trapping on direct responses to my request (and if so, why)?  The webserver is sending back 3 streams (verified by wireshark) but my proxy only gets one of them.

The System.Net.HttpListener is supposed to be trapping everything on port 80 (http://*:80/ or //+:80/) but it's not doing what I want.
Any help?  I can provide as much info as someone needs to help!!!

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Since you said HttpListener is used in a proxy service, then I'm guessing that you are using HttpWebRequest to make the outbound requests to the next service in the stack.

The 302 status code causes HttpWebRequest to throw an exception of type WebException.  If the WebException.Status is WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError then you need to check the status code and get the response handle out of the exception, like below for codes that you want to return back to the caller.  The example below shows this for a 304, but the same applies for a 302.

Hope this helps!

```
bool protocolError = false;
try
{
    webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.EndGetResponse(arGetResponse);
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;

        // 304s throw an exception... ridiculous!
        if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
        {
            // This indicates that the response is valid but has a protocol-level error like 404
            protocolError = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```